# Python pandas: appending information to row while looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, append

I would like to know a better way to append information to a dataframe while in a loop. Specifically, to add COLUMNS of information to a dataframe in a conditional manner. The code below technically works, but other than the fact that it is sloppy, more importantly, information such as the data type in each cell is lost as everything is converted to a string. Any tips would be great.

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['John', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
'age': [42, 20, 16, 24, '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])
headers = df.columns.values
count = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count += 1
    if row['age'] > 18:

        adult = True
    else:
        adult = False
    headers = np.append(headers,'ADULT')
    vals = np.append(row.values,adult)
    if count == 1:
        print ','.join(headers.tolist())
        print str(vals.tolist()).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
    else:
        print str(vals.tolist()).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to give your desired outcome (at least, it's the same outcome as your loop):

```
df['ADULT'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df.age) > 18, True, False)

>>> df
  first_name last_name age  ADULT
0       John    Miller  42   True
1      Molly  Jacobson  20   True
2       Tina       Ali  16  False
3       Jake    Milner  24   True
4        Amy     Cooze      False
```

As pointed out by @Wen, this is *much* more straightforward:

```
df['ADULT'] = pd.to_numeric(df.age) > 18
```

Comment: The output here is not the same as it has 4 data points, whereas there should be 5. The blank value was deleted (Amy). If I delete the first line I get the same results

Comment: @Rob, edited. When I ran your loop, I thought it got rid of the blank string, but I must have misread.

Comment: why not just `pd.to_numeric(df.age) > 18`